# How to send email at specied time and date in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

after selecting lead and if Email button from ribbon is selected , then email form opens , here is it possible to set time and date for email to be send.

i tried "Actual start , Actual end , Due date etc" but mails sends immediatly after send button is pressed.

Is there any other ways to set Date and time for sending email.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a great out of the box solution for what you are looking for.  However, depending on which version of CRM you are using (online vs on premise) You can create workflow that will fire off of one of those date fields being set (or a custom one) and wait until that specified time.  To actually send it you will have create a workflow assembly (on prem only at this time I believe) to send that e-mail record out.

If it is online or you want to not add any code you can still do this trick.  There are some drawbacks such as the e-mail would be text only, not able to recreate the activity party lists and some other things.  Here is what I would do.

1. Create a new entity called Scheduled E-mail
2. Create all of the e-mail fields that you need to recreate as well as a date field to send the e-mail out by.
3. Create the workflow on the Scheduled E-mail entity to wait until the specified date.
4. After the step use the "Send E-mail" step to send the e-mail and copy over all of the fields you need.

This isn't a perfect solution, but will work with no code.

Hope this helps!